# JTable with less row entries than displayed and sorting issues

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I'm using a JTable object to show some datas stored into a database.
Now I would like to achieve the following result:

The displayed JTable must have at least n (let it be 10 ) rows even if my db table has less entry. The empty row must always be displayed at the end of the table.

Since now I do the following:

I implemented my custom tabel model extending AbstractTableModel. And in the implemented method getRowCount I did:

```
public int getRowCount() {
       if (myRowCount < 10 )

           return 10;
       else 
           return myRowCount;
}
```

Questions are:

1. This code works fine, but I was
   wondering if this is the right
   approach to achieve this result. Is
   this a good solution?
2. In addition to that, if I try sort
   the row I got an undesired output. In fact empty rows seems to be taked in account while sorting, producing the result that (for example ordering a colum of int in descendant order) empty rows are displayed at the beginning of the table. Do I have to implement my custom TableRowSorter to avoid that behavior, or is it possible with the default one (table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)) ?

thanks in advance

EDIT:
i read @mKorbel links with @kleopatra @camickr [posts](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1349003&start=0&tstart=0). It help me a lot. But I really want to do that in the cleanest way as possible, because this class will be very important in my application.
Is the solution proposed in the previous linked post clean enough? Or it has some disadvantages that I can't see right now?

I started a bounty. Please give me good advices!!
thanks..

Marco

Comment: What do you do with empty rows? Are they here just to use empty space (for visuals only) or the suer may select them and possibly edit them? I ask because for visuals only, there better ways than what you're doing, since TableModel shouldn't be concerned with visuals.

Comment: @0verbose "The empty row must always be displayed at the end of the table." is possible to create RowFilter#public boolean include() that's ignore null or empty Row(s) from AbstractTableModel, but really better is set BackGround Color for ViewPort, but I never satisfied with that, nor talking about performance (for JTable with 10 rows too)

Comment: @jfpoilpret: it depends. Anyway yes, if the table is editable the user can select empty rows and edit it.

Comment: @mKorbel: could you make an example?

Comment: Then, to answer question #1, I think your solution is good (I don't see any possibly better solution). For question #2, since your table model includes (and has to include) the empty rows, then you have to specially deal with them in a TableRowSorter.

Comment: @0verbose link for good example (better as I tried, and described in English language, and not in my Navajo) http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1349003&start=0&tstart=0 and http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=6494092&#6494092 http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=5691715&#5691715 sure for these examples just kleopatra or camickr can show us correct direction ...

Comment: @camickr  Rob, please can you look in this topic and give us your comment/dirrection for this issue

Comment: @0verbose easiest way will be put there two JTables, sure 2.nd could be countains only empty rows, your idea is too hard, so hard job and with uncertain results, :-) forgot about that, its possible, but... :-) and between two JTables you can share majorities of methods and Listeners ...

Comment: I implemented that following this example you linked to me : http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1349003&start=0&tstart=0 . Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to edit these empty rows, then I guess the only way is to override `DefaultRowSorter`s `getComparator(column)` method.

**EDIT** I thought you could either override getComparator(), or set a Comparator to each column so that it checks if one of the values is null etc. I tried it, it didn't work, because there are null checks in the DefaultRowSorter, and there are other problems.

Unfortunately, most stuff in DefaultRowSorter is private, so there's not much room for customising. If you want this behaviour, you'd have to write your own implementation of RowSorter. I'd recommend you to take this approach only if this functionality is absolutely critical to your app.

Comment: @could you expand a little bit your answer? how do I need to modify getComparator behavior in order to accomplish my requirements?

Comment: @0verbose: sorry, my suggestion turned out to be wrong. see my edit.

Comment: @tulskiy: thanks. I need to implement this. It's a job requirement. Anyway it seems to me a bit strange that JTable doesn't hand such a situation. I think having a displayed table with empty rows was quite a common situation, isn't that?

Comment: @0verbose: frankly, I'm not aware of any application that has this functionality except for spreadsheet apps. Showing extra rows is common, but sorting them this way isn't.

Comment: @0verbose this is the only useful solution, to override the comparator. Consider what you're asking in terms of javascript, is "" less than "1"? Yes it is. Those are given the value of zero, as is the want of javascript, for comparison purposes. Try testing this with a negative "key" and see what it does then ;)  [ps: I realize this is a java question, not javascript, but I'm illustrating a point, not a fact of life in regards this question]