# JTable method called when sorting by column

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

Is there any method in JTable (or in a related class) that is called when user click on the column header to sort the relative column?
I would like to perform some operations when a user click happens on a column header, before that the sorting operation begin. is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[javax.swing.RowFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TestTableRowTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                        if (info.getName().equals("Nimbus")) {
                            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                final JTable table = new JTable(10, 6);
                for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    table.setValueAt(i, i, 0);
                }
                final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table.getModel());
                table.setRowSorter(sorter);
                final AbstractTableModel model = new AbstractTableModel() {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public int getColumnCount() {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
                        return table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getRowCount() {
                        return table.getRowCount();
                    }
                };
                JTable headerTable = new JTable(model);
                headerTable.setShowGrid(false);
                headerTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
                headerTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(30, 0));
                headerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(30);
                headerTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {

                    @Override
                    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable x, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

                        boolean selected = table.getSelectionModel().isSelectedIndex(row);
                        Component component = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer().getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, false, false, -1, -2);
                        ((JLabel) component).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                        if (selected) {
                            component.setFont(component.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
                        } else {
                            component.setFont(component.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
                        }
                        return component;
                    }
                });
                table.getRowSorter().addRowSorterListener(
                        new RowSorterListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e) {
                                model.fireTableDataChanged();
                            }
                        });
                table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
                        new ListSelectionListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                                model.fireTableRowsUpdated(0, model.getRowCount() - 1);
                            }
                        });
                JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
                pane.setRowHeaderView(headerTable);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Toggle filter") {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    private RowFilter<TableModel, Object> filter = new RowFilter<TableModel, Object>() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean include(javax.swing.RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Object> entry) {
                            return ((Number) entry.getValue(0)).intValue() % 2 == 0;
                            //return ((String) entry.getValue(0)).length()>0 ;
                            //return ((Date) entry.getValue(0)).getTime()< ;
                        }
                    };

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (sorter.getRowFilter() != null) {
                            sorter.setRowFilter(null);
                        } else {
                            sorter.setRowFilter(filter);
                        }
                    }
                }), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private TestTableRowTable() {
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thanks.. I was still working on this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138230/jtable-with-less-row-entries-than-displayed-and-sorting-issues. I was wondering that maybe changing for a while the rows number before sorting the table, and then reset the right row number after sorting, could be a workaround for null row entries.. +1 anyway :)

Comment: @0verbose don't forget for fact that if you'll set RowFilter to the concrete TableColumn, then another TableColumns ignore that

Comment: -1 this is completely _wrong_ (whatever it is supposed to be doing) ... you _must not_ (never-ever, it's an absolute nogo) fire fake events, especially not from listeners to other event type. If the model is changed in any respect, it's the mode's responsibility to do so. If the model is not changed, there is no need to fire (it would confuse all listeners)

Answer (score 0):

In Java5 you would subclass BasicTableHeaderUI and override [createMouseInputListener()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTableHeaderUI.html#createMouseInputListener%28%29), which is declared protected for this very purpose to return a custom listener

In Java6 lot of swing has been changed, not sure how its done there.